# EclipseLink doesn't create tables out of EntityClass

Tags: spring, jpa, entity, eclipselink, persistence.xml

I'm using EclipseLink and Spring.

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence persistence_1_0.xsd" version="2.0"> 

<persistence-unit name="tpcw" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> 
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.model.jpa.Address</class>
    <class>eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.model.jpa.Author</class>
    <class>eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.model.jpa.CcXacts</class>
    <class>eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.model.jpa.Country</class>
    <class>eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.model.jpa.Customer</class>
    <class>eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.model.jpa.Item</class>
    <class>eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.model.jpa.OrderLine</class>
    <class>eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.model.jpa.Orders</class>
    <class>eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.model.jpa.ShoppingCart</class>
    <class>eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.model.jpa.ShoppingCartLine</class>
    <class>eu.cloudscale.showcase.multiTenancy.model.SharedMetaData</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes> 

    <properties> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tpcw"/> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="12345"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>  
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.allow-native-sql-queries" value="true"/>
    </properties> 
</persistence-unit> 

</persistence>
```

And this is my spring-config-file.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.dao.jpa.impl" />
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method ="close"> 
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="150" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="dataSources">
            <map>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>jdbc/__default</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="dataSource" />
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>jdbc/jta</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="dataSource" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="service" class="eu.cloudscale.showcase.db.services.JPAService">
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />   

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="tpcw" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

All tables are created except of CcXacts and OrderLine. 
This is the CcXacts Entity Class:

```
@Entity(name="cc_xacts") 
@Table( name = "cc_xacts", catalog = "tpcw" )
@Multitenant(MultitenantType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "TENANT_ID", primaryKey = true)
public class CcXacts implements ICcXacts, Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = IDENTITY )
@Column( name = "CX_O_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer  id;

@ManyToOne( targetEntity=Orders.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn( name = "CX_O_ID", referencedColumnName = "CX_O_ID", nullable = false),
    @JoinColumn( name= "TENANT_ID", referencedColumnName = "TENANT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })

private IOrders  orders;

@Column( name = "CX_TYPE", length = 10 )
private String   cxType;

@Column( name = "CX_CC_NUM" )
private Integer  cxNum;

@Column( name = "CX_CC_NAME", length = 31 )
private String   cxName;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column( name = "CX_EXPIRY", length = 10 )
private Date     cxExpiry;

@OneToOne( targetEntity=Author.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn( name = "CX_AUTH_ID", referencedColumnName = "CX_AUTH_ID", nullable = false),
    @JoinColumn( name= "TENANT_ID", referencedColumnName = "TENANT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
private IAuthor  cxAuthId;

@Column( name = "CX_XACT_AMT", precision = 15)
private Double   cxXactAmt;

@Column( name = "CX_XACT_DATE", length = 19)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date     cxXactDate;


@ManyToOne( targetEntity=Country.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn( name = "CX_CO_ID", referencedColumnName = "CX_CO_ID", nullable = false),
    @JoinColumn( name= "TENANT_ID", referencedColumnName = "TENANT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
private ICountry country;

@Override
public Integer getId()
{
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public void setId(Integer string)
{
    this.id = string;
}


@Override
public IOrders getOrders()
{
    return this.orders;
}

@Override
public void setOrders(IOrders orders)
{
    this.orders = orders;
}


@Override
public String getCxType()
{
    return this.cxType;
}

@Override
public void setCxType(String cxType)
{
    this.cxType = cxType;
}


@Override
public Integer getCxNum()
{
    return this.cxNum;
}

@Override
public void setCxNum(Integer cxNum)
{
    this.cxNum = cxNum;
}


@Override
public String getCxName()
{
    return this.cxName;
}

@Override
public void setCxName(String cxName)
{
    this.cxName = cxName;
}


@Override
public Date getCxExpiry()
{
    return this.cxExpiry;
}

@Override
public void setCxExpiry(Date cxExpiry)
{
    this.cxExpiry = cxExpiry;
}


@Override
public IAuthor getCxAuthId()
{
    return this.cxAuthId;
}

@Override
public void setCxAuthId(IAuthor cxAuthId)
{
    this.cxAuthId = cxAuthId;
}


@Override
public Double getCxXactAmt()
{
    return this.cxXactAmt;
}

@Override
public void setCxXactAmt(Double o_TOTAL)
{
    this.cxXactAmt = o_TOTAL;
}


@Override
public Date getCxXactDate()
{
    return this.cxXactDate;
}

@Override
public void setCxXactDate(Date cxXactDate)
{
    this.cxXactDate = cxXactDate;
}


@Override
public ICountry getCountry()
{
    return this.country;
}

@Override
public void setCountry(ICountry country)
{
    this.country = country;
}
}
```

And this is the OrderLine EntityClass:

```
@Entity(name="order_line")
@Table( name = "order_line", catalog = "tpcw" )
@Multitenant(MultitenantType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn( name = "TENANT_ID", primaryKey = true)
public class OrderLine implements IOrderLine, Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = IDENTITY )
@Column( name = "OL_ID")
private Integer     id;

@ManyToOne( targetEntity=Orders.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumns( {
    @JoinColumn( name= "TENANT_ID", referencedColumnName ="TENANT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false), 
    @JoinColumn( name = "OL_O_ID", referencedColumnName = "OL_O_ID",  nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)})
private IOrders  orders;

@ManyToOne( targetEntity=Item.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumns( {
    @JoinColumn( name= "TENANT_ID", referencedColumnName ="TENANT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false), 
    @JoinColumn( name = "OL_I_ID", referencedColumnName = "OL_I_ID",  nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)})

private IItem    item;

@Column( name = "OL_QTY")
private Integer olQty;

@Column( name = "OL_DISCOUNT")
private Double olDiscount;

@Column( name = "OL_COMMENT", length = 100)
private String  olComment;

public OrderLine()
{
}


public Integer getOlId()
{
    return this.id;
}

public void setOlId(Integer olId)
{
    this.id = olId;
}


public IOrders getOrders()
{
    return this.orders;
}

public void setOrders(IOrders orders)
{
    this.orders = orders;
}


public IItem getItem()
{
    return this.item;
}

public void setItem(IItem item)
{
    this.item = item;
}


public Integer getOlQty()
{
    return this.olQty;
}

public void setOlQty(Integer olQty)
{
    this.olQty = olQty;
}


public Double getOlDiscount()
{
    return this.olDiscount;
}

public void setOlDiscount(Double oL_DISCOUNT)
{
    this.olDiscount = oL_DISCOUNT;
}


public String getOlComment()
{
    return this.olComment;
}

public void setOlComment(String olComment)
{
    this.olComment = olComment;
}

}
```

Does anyone know why the tables aren't created ? Thanks !

Comment: What is different from the entities that have their tables created?  Are there any errors/warnings in the logs if you set logging to Fine?

Comment: There is no difference, I checked it. The other entities are marked with the same annotations, statements etc.